# How to extract specific data from a downloaded csv file and transpose into a new csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with an online survey application that allows me to download survey results into a csv file.  However, the format of the downloaded csv puts each survey question and answer in a new column, whereas, I need the csv file to be formatted with each survey question and answer on a new row.  There is also a lot of data in the downloaded csv file that I want to ignore completely.

How can I parse out the desired rows and columns of the downloaded csv file and write them to a new csv file in a specific format?

For example, I download data and it looks like this:

```
V1,V2,V3,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4....
null,null,null,item,item,item,item....
0,0,0,4,5,4,5.... 
0,0,0,2,3,2,3....
```

The first row contains the 'keys' that I will need except V1-V3 must be excluded. Row 2 must be excluded altogether. Row 3 is my first subject so I need the values 4,5,4,5 to be paired with the keys Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4. And row 4 is a new subject which needs to be excluded as well since my program only handles one subject at a time.

The csv file that I need to create in order for my script to function properly looks like this:

```
Q1,4
Q2,5
Q3,4
Q4,5
```

I've tried using this izip to pivot the data, but I don't know how to specifically select the rows and columns I need:

```
from itertools import izip
a = izip(*csv.reader(open("CDI.csv", "rb")))
csv.writer(open("CDI_test.csv", "wb")).writerows(a)
```

Comment: Will there always be v1-v3 at the beginning of the first row or can that vary? Say v1-v5 and so on?

Comment: It is v1-v10 to be exact and yes those will always be at the beginning of the first row in each downloaded csv

Comment: however, some of the survey's vary where I will need to exclude Q1 as well as the preceding v1-v10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple python script that should do the job for you. It takes in arguments from the command line that designate the number of entries you want to skip at the beginning of the line,the input you want to skip at the end of the line, the input file and the output file. So for example, the command would look like

`python question.py 3:7 input.txt output.txt`

You can also substitute `sys.argv[1]` for 3, `sys.argv[2]` for "input.txt" and so on within the script if you don't want to state the arguments every time.

Text file version:

```
import sys

inputFile = open(sys.argv[2],"r")
outputFile = open(sys.argv[3], "w")
leadingRemoved=int(sys.argv[1])

#strips extra whitespace from each line in file then splits by ","
lines = [x.strip().split(",") for x in inputFile.readlines()]
#zips all but the first x number of elements in the first and third row
zipped = zip(lines[0][leadingRemoved:],lines[2][leadingRemoved:])
for tuples in zipped:
    #writes the question/ number pair to a file. 
    outputFile.write(",".join(tuples))

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()

#input from command line: python questions.py leadingRemoved pathToInput pathToOutput
```

CSV file version:

```
import sys
import csv


with open(sys.argv[2],"rb") as inputFile:
    #removes null bytes
    reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in inputFile),delimiter="\t")
    outputFile = open(sys.argv[3], "wb")
    leadingRemoved,endingremoved=[int(x) for x in sys.argv[1].split(":")]
    #creates a 2d array of all the elements for each row
    lines = [x for x in reader]
    print lines
    #zips all but the first x number of elements in the first and third row
    zipped = zip(lines[0][leadingRemoved:endingremoved],lines[2][leadingRemoved:endingremoved])
    writer = csv.writer(outputFile)
    writer.writerows(zipped)
    print zipped
    outputFile.close()
```

Comment: This sounds very promising, thank you.  I just tried it with my data and it's producing a blank csv file. I don't think there are any tuples being created

Comment: Sorry that is because you are using a csv file. If you change it to text this solution will work but I will hammer out a csv solution for you as well.

Comment: Edit made. try removing null bytes

Comment: hmm, it's coming out with a blank csv again. The 'zipped' variable is an empty array; I'm not sure why the zip isn't working properly

Comment: is there anyway I could download one of these CSVs for myself? seems like there is some unusual data in there

Comment: is there a way I can send you the file? there is a bit of unusual data in the csv

Comment: Thanks!! Awesome, your edited answer just solved it. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Something similar I did using multiple values but could be changed to single values.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python


import csv

def dict_from_csv(filename):
    '''
    (file)->list of dictionaries
    Function to read a csv file and format it to a list of dictionaries.
    The headers are the keys with all other data becoming values
    The format of the csv file and the headers included need to be know to extract the email addresses
    '''

    #open the file and read it using csv.reader()
    #read the file. for each row that has content add it to list mf
    #the keys for our user dict are the first content line of the file mf[0]
    #the values to our user dict are the other lines in the file mf[1:]
    mf = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        my_file = csv.reader(f)
        for row in my_file:
            if any(row):
                mf.append(row)
    file_keys = mf[0]
    file_values= mf[1:]  #choose row/rows you want

    #Combine the two lists, turning into a list of dictionaries, using the keys list as the key and the people list as the values
    my_list = []
    for value in file_values:
        my_list.append(dict(zip(file_keys, file_values)))

    #return the list of dictionaries
    return my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up on pandas for this type of activity:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

```
import pandas

input_dataframe = pandas.read_csv("input.csv")
transposed_df = input_dataframe.transpose()

# delete rows and edit data easily using pandas dataframe
# this is a good library to get some experience working with

transposed_df.to_csv("output.csv")
```